# What signal emitted when hide a row or column in QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

As QTableView has public function setRowHidden() and setColumnHidden(), but if person A performs hide operation, how can person B get to know the changes? If there is a signal available that gives an idea about the geometry changes in QTableView ?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the happiest mood, I finally found the solution to observe the hide/show behavior of a row/column in tableView. The method still goes-back to the signal/slot mechanism. Just because of strange terminology in Qt's system, some concepts are really not very straight-forward and confusing.

```
QTableView *tableView = new QTableView;
tableView->setRowHidden(0, true);
```

This will make a tableView's the 0st row hide. This operation actually just makes the row's section resizes. The result of this is the size of the section is ZERO, and signal sectionResized() emitted.

Comment: You mean `QHeaderView`? `QTableView` does not have `sectionResized`signal.

Comment: yes, vertical & horizontal QHeaderView emit sectionResized signal when tableview's view changed. And actually, I think section is the only entry to access to and manipulate the tableView's rendering.

Answer (score 1):

No, signal is not emitted an doc doesn't say anything about it, but you can make it easily by yourself. 
Just create subclass of `QTableView` and override `setRowHidden` and `setColumnHidden` methods, call original methods and add your signal emissions inside. Something like that:
**MyTableView.h**

```
#include <QTableView>

class MyTableView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTableView(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MyTableView();
    void setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide);
    void setRowHidden(int row, bool hide);


signals:
    void columnHidden(int column, bool hide);
    void rowHidden(int row, bool hide);

};
```

**MyTableView.cpp**

```
#include "mytableview.h"

MyTableView::MyTableView(QWidget *parent) : QTableView(parent)
{

}

MyTableView::~MyTableView()
{

}

void MyTableView::setRowHidden(int row, bool hide)
{
    QTableView::setRowHidden(row, hide);
    emit rowHidden(row, hide);
}

void MyTableView::setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide)
{
    QTableView::setColumnHidden(column, hide);
    emit columnHidden(column, hide);
}
```

Now you can call your overloaded methods just like the original ones.

Comment: I found some signals in QHeaderView, and hope to use them. I think these signals may help me to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't quite work as you expect because `setColumnHidden` is NOT a `virtual` method.